# Is There Any Way to Get a File Select To Work in Webview on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, filechooser

I hope someone can answer this because I have searched everywhere. As we all know, Android 4.4's Chromium Webview does not support the FileChooser API as previous versions had. With that said, **how can I make an input with type="file" open the file selector in webview and have it work on 4.4 as well as earlier versions?** My apps absolutely hinge on users being able to upload photos to their profiles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only a complex native solution or apply pressure on Google by posting on this bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

Answer (score 0):

Cordova has a plugin which you might use as a **basis** for a solution - https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser.  This retrieves the filename which you could then feed to a file uploader.